# jquery toggle between the two divs

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and trying to work out how to achieve the following...

I have two div shown below, I want `group` div to show on load but not `single` div then onclick of `group` or `single` I need toggle between the two. How can this be done. This is what I have so far.

```
Send to: <a href="">Group</a> | <a href=""> Single<</a>

<div id="group">I'm a group</div>
<div id="single">I'm a single object</div>
```

UPDATE:

So something like this seems to work for me....

```
 $("#link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#divA, #divB").toggle();
      $(this).text(function(i, text) { return (text == "Show viewA") ? "Show viewB" : "Show viewA" });
    });
```

but divB does not show.

Comment: look at jQuery .click() (http://api.jquery.com/click/) and jQuery .toggle() (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) methods. Then maybe post what you have tried.

Comment: cool, toggle() looks like what I need.

Comment: Yep, to toggle, you need toggle(). Makes sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example I have create a simple script that will work nice for your needs.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var $divA = $('#a'),
    $divB = $('#b'),
    $link = $('#link');
    $diplaytext = $('#display_text');

  // Initialize everything
  $link.text( 'Show Single' );
  $diplaytext.text( 'Group' );
  $divA.hide();

  $link.click(function(){

  // If A is visible when the link is clicked
  // you need to hide A and show B
  if( $divA.is( ':visible' ) ){
    $link.text( 'Show Single' );
    $diplaytext.text( 'Group' );
    $divA.hide();
    $divB.show();
  } else {
    $link.text( 'Show Group' );
    $diplaytext.text( 'Single Here' );
    $divA.show();
    $divB.hide();
  }

  return false;
  });


  });
</script>
```

then...

```
display text: <span id="display_text"></span> | change: <a href="#" id="link" ></a>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to the following

```
Send to: <a data-div="group" href="#">Group</a> | <a data-div="single" href="#"> Single</a>

<div id="group">I'm a group</div>
<div id="single">I'm a single object</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#single").css("display", "none");
        $("a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the link behaviour
            $("div").css("display", "none");
            $("#"+ $(this).attr("data-div")).css("display", "block");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, had a typo, check now. It's been fixed

Answer (score 2):

Just hide them all, then unhide the one that was just clicked.

```
Send to: <a href="#" data-target="group" class="target">Group</a> | <a href="#" data-target="group" class="target">Single</a>

<div id="group" class="toggle">I'm a group</div>
<div id="single" class="toggle">I'm a single object</div>
```

Then use this jQuery:

```
$('.target').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $( '#' + $(this).data('target') ).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to switch between two `div` elements:

```
$("#show_Blue").click(function(){
 $("#Blue").toggle();
 $("#Red").hide();
});

$("#show_Red").click(function(){
 $("#Red").toggle();
 $("#Blue").hide();
});
```

There's a demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/z1w1p3o1/)